# Unable to kubectl apply -f to my EKS cluster : Access denied (Roles may not be assumed by root accounts)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I created a Kubernetes cluster on AWS EKS and now I'm trying to deploy an app using cmd :

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

But I'm getting this error :

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Roles may not be assumed by root accounts.
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable aws failed with exit code 254
```

I'm new to AWS and EKS and when I did some Google research it says that it might be caused by the authenticated user in `aws` cli tool.

For information, my cli is connected with a user called **aws_cli_user** who has `AdministratorAccess` strategy.

And for creating k8s cluster, I created a role called **EksSocaClusterRole** who has `AmazonEKSClusterPolicy`.

I think I'm missing something to link both the role and the user so It can push things to the cluster correctly !

Comment: 1. share please steps hor you created eks clusted

Comment: 2.saw that? didnt helped in investigation? [Why did I receive an "AccessDenied" or "Invalid information" error trying to assume an IAM role?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-assume-role-error/)

Comment: 1. Actually I used the AWS Dashboard (UI) to create the cluster and then I used `aws eks --region region update-kubeconfig --name cluster_name` so I can change my `kubectl` context to use the freshly created cluster.

Comment: You nee to access the cluster with the same user/role you created it with. This is important, because intially only the creator is the only Admin cluster internally. If you created it with a role add  `--role-arn` to the `aws eks --region region update-kubeconfig --name cluster_name` be forehand